# JToken.FromObject on notnull object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following extension method:

```
public static T FromJson<T>(JToken json) where T : notnull  => json.ToObject<T>();
```

Upgrading to latest Json.NET I now get:

> Possible null reference return.

Considering the template restriction is this error safe to ignore ? that is can I add exclamation mark like this?

```
public static T FromJson<T>(JToken json) where T : notnull  => json.ToObject<T>()!;
```

Comment: Not necessarily.  The return from [`JValue.CreateNull()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_CreateNull.htm) is a non-null `JToken` corresponding to the JSON string `null`, but if you deserialize it to a non-nullable reference type I believe Json.NET will still return `null`.

Comment: Yes, looks like your method `JsonExtensions.FromJson<SomeReferenceType>(JValue.CreateNull())` will return `null`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/LwqZc8, because a non-null `JToken` can deserialize to a `null` value.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/LwqZc8.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in above comments by @dbc `json.ToObject<T>()` can still return null even when `T` is constraint to `notnull`

I ended up with:

```
public static T FromJson<T>(JToken json) where T : notnull => json.ToObject<T>() ?? throw new ArgumentException(typeof(T).ToString());
```

Comment: Why do you throw `NRE` instead of `ArgumentException` or any of its derived exception?

Comment: Good question .. changed